# Scale down svg without breaking the image

Tags: floats, svg

I want to resize included svg, and it partially works. Svg takes less space, but it's "squeezed" and a lot of elements in svg image overlap each other. Here is what I have but with `\textwidth` size.

```latex
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includesvg[width=\textwidth]{img1.svg}
\caption{Caption.}
\label{fig3}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You could either reduce the font size with something like `\includesvg[width=\textwidth,pretex=\small]` or just wrap `\resizebox` around `\includesvg`